# Flow type an array of values with generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

The following code

```
type Value<T> = {|
  name: string,
  value: T,
|}

const myNumber: Value<number> = { name: 'number', value: 1 };
const myString: Value<string> = { name: 'string', value: 'foo' };

const arr: Array<Value> = [myNumber, myString];
```

I want to loop through an array of `Value` objects and get the `name` value of all my objects, but I'm getting this error:

```
9: const arr: Array<Value> = [myNumber, myString];
                    ^ Cannot use `Value` [1] without 1 type argument.
References:
1: type Value<T> = {|
             ^ [1]
```

Any ideas how to fix this without using `Value<any>`? I'm using `flow strict`

Flow Playground [link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QDwBUB8UC8UDeAPgFBRQB2cAthAFxQDOwATgJbkDmANKVAG6IU9dD0IBfYsQDGAe3JMoVEADkkVAEYRm9eMjTk1m5tjz4K1OlADkBjVqtd+gywEYoYgNzS5CpQGUWdg4dZ1QmNk4TAnMaeitwoIcnPTiAMxkZK3cvb3lgKDhmbSgAQSK4EFRdFCiAbSVVO2ZHf0DOAF0PIA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
In latest version (tested with 0.98.0) flow is able to infer the types properly, so explicit annotation is no longer required. Just go with:

```
const arr = [myNumber, myString];
```

---

**Older versions:**

In flow you could use [Existential Type (*)](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-existential-type)

> An existential type is used as a placeholder to tell Flow to infer the type

```
const arr: Array<*> = [myNumber, myString];
```

[Playground](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QDwBUB8UC8UDeAPgFBRQB2cAthAFxQDOwATgJbkDmANKVAG6IU9dD0IBfYsQDGAe3JMoVEADkkVAEYRm9eMjTk1m5tjz4K1OlADkBjVqtd+gywEYoYgNzS5CpQGUWdg4dZ1QmNk4TAnMaeitwoIcnPTiAMxkZK3cvb3lgKDhmbSgAQSK4EFQAKiiAbSVVO2ZHf0DOAF0PIA)

Comment: Existential seems deprecated and not recommended though :/

Comment: Well, it wasn't (at least according to docs) when the answer was added. I'll update.

Comment: @YangshunTay apparently explicit annotation is no longer needed

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type argument for the array item type

```
type Value<T> = {|
  name: string,
  value: T,
|}

const myNumber: Value<number> = { name: 'number', value: 1 };
const myString: Value<string> = { name: 'string', value: 'foo' };

const arr: Array<Value<any>> = [myNumber, myString];
```

Depending on how strict you want to be you could also use an array with a union type as an item

```
 const arr: Array<Value<number>|Value<string>> = [myNumber, myString];
```

Or a tuple type :

```
const arr: [Value<number>,Value<string>] = [myNumber, myString];
```

You could also skip the annotation and let the compiler infer the type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have been clearer. I don't want to use `any` as I'm using `flow strict`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this as I don't really need to know the type of `value`.

```
type Value<T> = {|
  name: string,
  value: T,
|}

const myNumber: Value<number> = { name: 'number', value: 1 };
const myString: Value<string> = { name: 'string', value: 'foo' };

const arr: Array<{name: string}> = [myNumber, myString];
```

[Playground Link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QDwBUB8UC8UDeAPgFBRQB2cAthAFxQDOwATgJbkDmANKVAG6IU9dD0IBfYsQDGAe3JMoVEADkkVAEYRm9eMjTk1m5tjz4K1OlADkBjVqtd+gywEYoYgNzS5CpQGUWdg4dZ1QmNk4TAnMaeitwoIcnPTiAMxkZK3cvb3lgKDhmbSgAQSK4EFR8SljGQM4xKIBtJVU7Zkd-eo4AXQ8gA)